# Using DevOps pipelines to create distribution bundles of applications

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, continuous-delivery

We want to create bundles of our applications in order to distribute to clients etc. An application can have more than one component. Ex: an application can have a spring server and a scheduler so in order to distribute this application both jars will have to be given to the client.

We want to use Docker/Docker compose to accomplish this. Ex: we give a client a bundle containing a Docker compose file, and they just run `docker-compose up` to start the application.

We currently have a Jenkins pipeline that when run will produce a zip file containing `.tar` files of all the Docker images of the components. There will also be a `start.sh` (or `start.bat`) file that, when run, will load all the Docker images and run `docker-compose up`.

Some of these components have properties that the client needs to configure according to their environment (ex: SCM URL). If the component is Spring/Java based, we would externally mount the application.properties file into the docker image in the `docker-compose.yml`

This all works, I just want to know if the current process we are using is compliant with industry standards or is there a better way of meeting the requirement? Any open source tools that would simplify the process?

UPDATE:
The only "problem" we ran into while doing the above process is having to change the configuration properties to fit with our docker-compose environment. For example in one of the `application.properties` files that the developer has checked in to the SCM he has specified the MySQL host as `localhost` whereas when deploying in our Docker compose environment the MySQL container will have a host name `mysql`. How do we handle a problem like this? In a Java/Spring application do we use profiles? Ex: `application-dev.properties` & `application-docker.properties`. Or is there a better way to do application configuration management

Comment: Depending on your specific needs, it's probably easier to upload the images to a Docker registry (could be Docker Hub or something you host yourself) than to use a `docker save` tar file.  Nothing you discuss sounds wrong; is there a specific problem you're running into?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks a lot for the reply.. I updated the question a bit. Could you please check when possible?