# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

This question ties in with one of my earlier questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631311/using-devops-pipelines-to-create-distribution-bundles-of-applications)

***Tl;dr of the linked question***:

Basically I want a generic pipeline to generate distributable bundles (zip files etc) of any of my  applications. An application can have multiple components (almost all components are Java/Spring or NodeJS projects).

The plan was to store a pipeline descriptor of each application in a JSON file like such:

```
{
    "app": "MyApp",
    "components": [
            {
                "name": "Component1",
                "scmUrl": "https://git.mycompany.com/app/component1.git",
                "buildCmd": "mvn clean install"
            },
            {
                "name": "Component2",
                "scmUrl": "https://git.mycompany.com/app/component2.git",
                "buildCmd": "npm run build"
            },
    ]
}
```

There will be a descriptor for each application and will be checked into separate repository.

When the pipeline is run the required application name will be an input parameter and the above repo will be cloned and the respective JSON descriptor will be loaded.

This is where things start to get tricky. All **components** will have some common stages (Checkout, Build, Docker Build). So I am trying to loop the components array and run the stages in parallel:

```
def parallelCheckoutStages = components.collectEntries {
    [ "Checkout ${it.name}", generateCheckoutStage(it) ]
}

generateCheckoutStage(component) {
    return {
        stage("Stage: ${component.name}") {
            script {
                git(url: component.scmUrl, branch:  component.branch)
            }
        }
    }
}

def parallelBuildStages = components.collectEntries {
    [ "Build ${it.name}", generateBuildStage(it) ]
}

generateBuildStage(component) {
    return {
        stage("Stage: ${component.name}") {
            script {
                sh script "${component.buildCmd}"
            }
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        .
        . // clone repo and load json 
        .
        stage("Checkout Components") {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelCheckoutStages
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Build Components") {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelBuildStages
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes I need run the build command inside a docker container (**only for some components**). To accomplish this I want to edit the `generateBuildStage` method to something like this:

```
generateBuildStage(component) {
    if(component.requiresDocker) {
        return {
            stage("Stage: ${component.name}") { 
                agent {
                    docker {
                        image 'jdk11-mvn3.6'
                    }
                }
                script {
                    sh script "${component.buildCmd}"
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        return {
            stage("Stage: ${component.name}") {
                script {
                    sh script "${component.buildCmd}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code I get an error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps`

Sort of a second part to my question, does my pipeline seem hacky? I could replace the entire parallel stages by creating individual jobs for each component and calling them from the pipeline. Which approach is better?

Comment: For your specific error, you would need to move the method invocation to an outer scope only inside the tip-level `stage` declaration block. `agent` cannot be declared as a block from within `steps`. For your other question, you have the right idea for the pipeline architecture, but the architecture you presented does not realize your idea. However, that kind of discussion falls outside SO and would be too much for a Q&A.